# Control-Delete hotkey does not delete next word

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

As said in the title, my <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> key combo does not delete the next word like it is supposed to.

My control key works fine, as is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>, and <kbd>Delete</kbd> by itself. However, when I try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, nothing happens.

I have Sticky/Filter/whatever Keys off. Both the external keyboard and the laptop keyboard do not do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> functionality.

Comment: In which product is this happening?

Comment: Essentially anywhere I can type in a text box.

Comment: Does this include Word and browser?

Comment: Yes. I started noticing this because I wanted to quickly edit some Google Docs.

Comment: Have you installed any product that does global hotkeys, like Autohotkeys?

Comment: Nope, no Autohotkey. Closest thing I can think of is ShareX, but that doesn't use the Delete key....

Comment: Does this happen if you boot in Safe mode?